# How to "refresh" a mounted NFS folder from my router in Finder?

Tags: macos, nfs

I have a rt-n56u router with an external hard disk shared in NFS.

Sometimes this shared disk shows in Finder, sometimes not, and I need to reboot router AND mac yosemite - even if I can see it being shared in my router's admin interface - to make it available in my sidebar. Sometimes, I need to wait some minutes for it to show.

What can I do to "force", "refresh", "flush cache" or something like this for my hard disk to show again without all this hassle? I'm fine with command line.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Connect to Server in Finder you can set the URL and force a refresh.  In Finder Go > Connect to Server or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> From there you can add the URL to your server.  [This Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204445) has further details.

I hope this helps.[image: Connect to Server dialog box]

Comment: It's NFS, not afp. I tried this command but it didn't work, I get "You don't have permission", and, after a few minutes, my Finder automatically connects to the NFS perfectly. That's what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't helpful. I did find this support [article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18718?locale=en_US) does refer to NFS.  You may have already come across this in your research though. Hope you find a solution.